# Verificar se um campo está com bindBidirectional (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx

Bom dia!!
Queria saber como eu verifico se um campo está com binding (javaFX)
tenho o seguinte campo:

```
txt2.textProperty().bindBidirectional(txt1.textProperty());
```

Tenhoum botão pra ativar ou desativar o bindBidirectional, conforme o estado atual. Se tiver com bind: desativar, se não estiver: ativar.
valeuu

Answer (score 0):

Basta usar o método .isBound() da propriedade:

```
if(txt2.textProperty().isBound()){
    // Propriedade linkada
}else{
    // Propriedade não linkada
}
```